# python shows a list indices must be integers, not tuple error

Tags: python

this is code from another user on my last post:

```
candidates = tempContestants[-2:]
if len(candidates) != 2:
    print("Sorry, not enough players")
    quit()
print("{} and {}, I'm sorry my dears but you are up for elimination".format(
        *candidates))
lipsync()

eliminated = random.choice(candidates)
candidates.remove(eliminated)
safe = candidates[0]
tempContestants.remove(eliminated)

print("""Ladies, I have made my decision.
{}, shantay you stay!
{}, sashay away!""".format(safe, eliminated))

if eliminated == name:
    print("You have been eliminated!")
    quit()
```

here's some bits you may need to know:

```
season_options = {
1: ["BeBe Zahara Benet", "Nina Flowers", "Rebecca Glasscock", "Shannel", "Ongina", "Jade", "Akashia", "Tammie Brown", "Victoria Parker"],
2: ["Tyra Sanchez", "Raven", "Jujubee", "Tatianna", "Pandora Boxx", "Jessica Wild", "Sahara Davenport", "Morgan McMichaels", "Sonique", "Mystique Summers Madison", "Nicole Paige Brooks", "Shangela"],
3: ["Raja", "Manila Luzon", "Alexis Mateo", "Yara Sofia", "Carmen Carrera", "Shangela", "Delta Work", "Stacy Layne Matthews", "Mariah", "India Ferrah", "Mimi Imfurst", "Phoenix", "Venus D-Lite"],
4: ["Sharon Needles", "Chad Michaels", "Phi Phi O'Hara", "Latrice Royale", "Kenya Michaels", "Dida Ritz", "Willam", "Jiggly Caliente", "Milan", "Madame LaQueer", "The Princess", "Lashauwn Beyond", "Alisa Summers"],
5: ["Jinkx Monsoon", "Alaska", "Roxxxy Andrews", "Detox", "Coco Montrese", "Alyssa Edwards", "Ivy Winters", "Jade Jolie", "Lineysha Sparx", "Honey Mahogany", "Vivienne Pinay", "Monica Beverly Hillz", "Serena ChaCha", "Penny Tration"],
6: ["Bianca Del Rio", "Courtney Act", "Adore Delano", "Darienne Lake", "BenDeLaCreme", "Joslyn Fox", "Trinity K. Bonet", "Laganja Estranja", "Milk", "Gia Gunn", "April Carrión", "Vivacious", "Magnolia Crawford", "Kelly Mantle"],
7: ["Violet Chachki", "Ginger Minj", "Pearl", "Kennedy Davenport", "Katya", "Trixie Mattel", "Miss Fame", "Jaidynn Diore Fierce", "Max", "Kandy Ho", "Mrs. Kasha Davis", "Jasmine Masters", "Sasha Belle", "Tempest DeJour"],
8: ["Bob the Drag Queen", "Kim Chi", "Naomi Smalls", "Chi Chi DeVayne", "Derrick Barry", "Thorgy Thor", "Robbie Turner", "Acid Betty", "Naysha Lopez", "Cynthia Lee Fontaine", "Dax ExclamationPoint", "Laila McQueen"],
9: ["Sasha Velour", "Peppermint", "Shea Couleé", "Trinity Taylor", "Alexis Michelle", "Nina Bo'nina Brown", "Valentina", "Farrah Moan", "Aja", "Cynthia Lee Fontaine", "Eureka", "Charlie Hides", "Kimora Blac", "Jaymes Mansfield"],
10: ["Aquaria", "Eureka", "Kameron Michaels", "Asia O'Hara", "Miz Cracker", "Monét X Change", "The Vixen", "Monique Heart", "Blair St. Clair", "Mayhem Miller", "Dusty Ray Bottoms", "Yuhua Hamasaki", "Kalorie Karbdaashian Williams", "Vanessa Vanjie Mateo"],
11: ["Yvie Oddly", "Brooke Lynn Hytes", "A'Keria C. Davenport", "Silky Nutmeg Ganache", "Vanessa Vanjie Mateo", "Nina West", "Shuga Cain", "Plastique Tiara", "Ra'Jah O'Hara", "Scarlet Envy", "Ariel Versace", "Mercedes Iman Diamond", "Honey Davenport", "Kahanna Montrese", "Soju"],
12: ["Chad Michaels", "Raven", "Shannel", "Jujubee", "Alexis Mateo", "Yara Sofia", "Latrice Royale", "Manila Luzon", "Nina Flowers", "Tammie Brown", "Pandora Boxx", "Mimi Imfurst"],
13: ["Alaska", "Katya", "Detox", "Roxxxy Andrews", "Alyssa Edwards", "Tatianna", "Phi Phi O'Hara", "Ginger Minj", "Adore Delano", "Coco Montrese"],
14: ["Trixie Mattel", "Kennedy Davenport", "Shangela", "BeBe Zahara Benet", "Morgan McMichaels", "BenDeLaCreme", "Aja", "Chi Chi DeVayne", "Milk", "Thorgy Thor"],
15: ["Trinity the Tuck", "Monét X Change", "Monique Heart", "Naomi Smalls", "Latrice Royale", "Manila Luzon", "Valentina", "Gia Gunn", "Farrah Moan", "Jasmine Masters"],
16: ["Gothy Kendoll", "Scaredy Kat", "Vinegar Strokes", "Sum Ting Wong", "Crytal", "Blu Hydrangea", "Cheryl Hole", "Baga Chipz", "Divina De Campo", "The Vivienne"]
}

group_options = {
1: ["BeBe Zahara Benet", "Tyra Sanchez", "Raja", "Sharon Needles", "Jinkx Monsoon", "Bianca Del Rio", "Violet Chachki", "Bob the Drag Queen", "Sasha Velour", "Aquaria", "Yvie Oddly", "Chad Michaels", "Alaska", "Trixie Mattel", "Trinity the Tuck", "Monét X Change", "The Vivienne"],
2: ["Nina Flowers", "Raven", "Manila Luzon", "Chad Micheals", "Alaska", "Courtney Act", "Ginger Minj", "Kim Chi", "Peppermint", "Eureka", "Brooke Lynn Hytes", "Katya", "Kennedy Davenport", "Monique Heart", "Divina De Campo"],
3: ["Akashia", "Jujubee", "Alexis Mateo", "Latrice Royale", "Coco Montrese", "Trinity K. Bonet", "Kennedy Davenport", "Chi Chi DeVayne", "Peppermint", "Kameron Michaels", "Ra'Jah O'Hara", "Raven", "Alaska", "BenDeLaCreme", "Trinity the Tuck", "Cheryl Hole"],
4: ["Nina Flowers", "Pandora Boxx", "Yara Sofia", "Latrice Royale", "Ivy Winters", "BenDeLaCreme", "Katya", "Cynthia Lee Fontaine", "Valentina", "Monét X Change", "Nina West"],
5: ["Victoria Parker", "Shangela", "Venus D-Lite", "Alisa Summers", "Penny Tration", "Kelly Mantle", "Tempest DuJour", "Laila McQueen", "Jaymes Mansfield", "Vanessa Vanjie Mateo", "Soju", "Mimi Imfurst", "Coco Montrese", "Thorgy Thor", "Jasmine Masters", "Gothy Kendoll"],
6: ["Carmen Carrera", "Shangela", "Kenya Michaels", "Trixie Mattel", "Naysha Lopez", "Cynthia Lee Fontaine", "Eureka", "Vanessa Vanjie Mateo", "Alyssa Edwards", "Tatianna", "Morgan McMichaels", "Latrice Royale", "Manila Luzon"]
}

print('''Which group of queens do you want to compete against?
1. Winners
2. Runner-ups
3. Lip sync assassins
4. Miss Congenialities
5. First Eliminated
6. Returning queens
7. One of the seasons''')

choice = int(input())
while choice > 7 or choice < 1:
    print("Please choose one of the 7 groups")
    choice = int(input())

if choice == 7:
    print('''
Choose a season:
1. Season 1
2. Season 2
3. Season 3
4. Season 4
5. Season 5
6. Season 6
7. Season 7
8. Season 8
9. Season 9
10. Season 10
11. Season 11
12. All Stars 1
13. All Stars 2
14. All Stars 3
15. All Stars 4
16. UK Season 1''')
    choice = int(input())
    while choice > 16 or choice < 1:
        print("Please choose one of the 16 seasons")
        choice = int(input())
    contestants = season_options[choice]
else:
    contestants = group_options[choice]

tempContestants = contestants
```

i use tempContestants so that I can remove the contestants from the list and add new ones without affecting the main contestants list. also, when i want to pick a random contestant i don't want the program to pick the same contestant for two different "categories" and hence i remove them from the list.

it throws up an error saying:

```
bottom = tempContestants[0,len(tempContestants)-1]
    TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

what does this mean and how do i fix?

Comment: Please post the full error, otherwise we can't help you. Your code doesn't show everything (for example the value of tempContenstants) and we also cannot know where exactly the error stems from without the full error full

Comment: "this is code from another user on my last post" isn't very helpful, either - please provide some context and explain what the code shall do.

Comment: The title says _tuple index out of range error_, yet the error message in the post mentions _list indices must be integers, not tuple_, which is clearly different. So which is it?

Comment: forgot to change title, it came up with a different error

Comment: its the one mentioned in the description

Comment: I added an answer regarding the error message at the bottom of your post. I is not clear where that appears in the listing you have shown above - you may want to streamline the question to actually clarify what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

The line `bottom = tempContestants[0, len(tempContestants)-1]` is incorrect. 
If you want to get the last element, it shall be `bottom = tempContestants[-1]` instead. You gave 2 values (a tuple) as an index, which is not allowed, as the error showed.

If you want to get a new list instead, you have to use slicing, that uses a colon instead of a comma:

```
tempContestants[:-1]  # get a copy without the last element
tempContestants[:]    # get a complete copy of the list
tempContestants[1:]   # get a copy without the first element
```

Answer (score -1):

`tempContestants[-2:]` means take the last two elements of tempContestants. If you have less than two, Python throws an out of range exception

Comment: Slicing does not produce `IndexError`.